# Parsing a JSON array with dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm having some trouble getting to the data I want to in the JSON file. Here is a shortened version of the output from my console:

```
{
    AUD =     {
        15m = "125.15547";
        24h = "124.74";
        buy = "121.0177";
        last = "125.15547";
        sell = "123.44883";
        symbol = "$";
    };
    BRL =     {
        15m = "120.34";
        24h = "120.34";
        buy = "120.34";
        last = "120.34";
        sell = "120.34";
        symbol = "R$";
    };
    CAD =     {
        15m = "129.08612";
        24h = "131.07";
        buy = "128.66227";
        last = "129.08612";
        sell = "129.08612";
        symbol = "$";
    };
}
```

I'm trying to parse the file using the built in JSON parsing library. Here is the parser in my  `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    _tickerArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSURL *tickerDataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://blockchain.info/ticker"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tickerDataURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);
    NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dataDictionary];
    for (NSString *key in [dataDictionary allKeys]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in ar) {
            TickerData *t;
            t.currency = [dict objectForKey:key];
            t.symbol = [dict objectForKey:@"symbol"];
            t.last = [dict objectForKey:@"last"];
            [_tickerArray addObject:t];
        }

    }
```

I want to store the currency code (like `AUD or BRL`) into `t.currency` along with some of the other data contained in the currency dictionary but now my app is crashing. 
Error code:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

None of the objects seem to get added to the `_tickerArray`

Help?

EDIT: Getting the keys to display with the proper data populating other fields:

```
 NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);


    for (NSString *key in [dataDictionary allKeys]) {
        NSDictionary *dic=[dataDictionary objectForKey:key];
            TickerData *t=[[TickerData alloc] init];
            t.currency = key;//EDITED
            t.symbol = [dic objectForKey:@"symbol"];
            t.last = [dic objectForKey:@"last"];
            [_tickerArray addObject:t];

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);
//NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dataDictionary];//REMOVED
for (NSString *key in [dataDictionary allKeys]) {
    NSDictionary *dic=[dataDictionary objectForKey:key];//ADDED
    for (NSString *dickey in [dic allKeys]) { //MODIFIED
        NSDictionary *dict=[dic objectForKey:dicKey];//ADDED
        TickerData *t=[[TickerData alloc] init];//ALLOC INIT ?
        t.currency = key;//EDITED
        t.symbol = [dict objectForKey:@"symbol"];
        t.last = [dict objectForKey:@"last"];
        [_tickerArray addObject:t];
    }

}
```

Your data doesn't contain any array, its all dictionaries, try the above code see comments too..

Hope it works..

**Edited:**

Yes you have initialize the object too, as suggested above in other answers..

Comment: It seems to work better than the code I had. Though I now get an error `__NSCFNumber objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7184550` with that instance being `dict` which according to my console is getting it's value from `15m` in the JSON file

Comment: Debug and try to correct, my code is untested though.. But your code will not work what you are trying to do..

Comment: +1! Small correction: `t.currency = [dict objectForKey:key]` should probably be `t.currency = [dict objectForKey:@"symbol"]`

Comment: @MartinR but I'm trying to get the Top-level dictionary name into `t.currency` not the symbol. For some reason I still can't get the data to display in the table. It does however display in my console

Comment: @iphonic that last edit did it! The key now displays in my table. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that you can simplify `for (NSString *key in [dataDictionary allKeys])` to `for (NSString *key in dataDictionary)`.

Answer (score 4):

`t` is nil, you have to alloc/ init it:

```
TickerData *t = [[TickerData alloc] init];
```

Comment: Well this doesn't cause a crash which is nice. But for some reason none of the labels that I put in my TableView seem to be getting the data. But everything is displaying properly in my console since I added an `NSLOG` outside of the for statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://blockchain.info/ticker"];

NSLog(@"API : %@",url);

NSMutableData *jsonData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [jsonData mutableBytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

dictionary = [data JSONValue];
NSDictionary *dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"AUD"];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
NSString *last = [dict valueForKey:@"last"];
NSLog(@"%@",last);
```