# How to parse JSON Parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I have some values in an array ,using dictionary I need to show these values through some key value

```
{
    "table_id": "180PTTBL",
    "table_name": "180 Points",
    "stake": 100,
    "game_type": "180PT"
}
```

Please help me out this problem

Comment: Your question have a duplicate. You can look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15802816/3137158)

Comment: @Balaji where u want in tableview or viewcontroller

Comment: -1 for not making the slightest effort to research your question first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSJSONSerialization

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!dict) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   .. do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *jsonString = @"YOUR_JSON_STRING";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"table_id"]);
```

Comment: -1 for not checking `error`.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: @IAmDav thanks its useful for me.

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks for your comment, I'll just write quick example :)
I think down vote used when answer is wrong, but mine is incomplete.

Comment: Code that does not check for errors is not complete.

Comment: @HotLicks I wrote the same, incomplete means not complete.

Comment: You were setting a bad example for an obvious newbie.