# Json result null from existing NSData iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsdata

I implemented this method to get json data from web server

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{ 
    magazineJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
}
```

and it returns `null`value however `data`is not an empty object.
I tried to do : `NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`and it returns an `NSString`that is divided into 3 parts, I don't know how to get my data into an `NSDictionary`
here is what I get in log when I try to get the string :

> 2015-03-23 17:35:15.638 AppTest[5604:70b] str is{"products":[{"id":74,"id_default_image":"351","manufacturer_name":"Bose","price":"449.990000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"BOSE enceinte soundlink mobile + casque AE2I"},{"id":"2","value":"Bose soundlink mobile + helmet AE2I"}]},{"id":76,"id_default_image":"5006","manufacturer_name":"Bose","price":"398.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"BOSE Enceintes 301 serie V X2"},{"id":"2","value":"Bose 301 series V X 2"}]},{"id":81,"id_default_image":"380","manufacturer_name":"Bose","price":"649.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"BOSE Enceintes freespace 51 (paire)"},{"id":"2","value":"Bose freespace 51 (pair)"}]},{"id":114,"id_default_image":"551","manufacturer_name":"Apple","price":"659.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Iphone 5s 32 Go"},{"id":"2","value":"Apple iphone 5S 32GO OR"}]},{"id":121,"id_default_image":"562","manufacturer_name":"De'Longhi","price":"279.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Machine à café Delonghi lattissima+ Nespresso argent givre EN520S"},{"id":"2","value":"Delonghi lattissima+ nespresso argent givre EN520S"}]},{"id":122,"id_default_image":"564","manufacturer_name":"Kitchen Chef","price":"350.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Kitchen chef ZB06B : fabrique à glaçons, producteur d'eau chaude (90°C) et d'eau froide (moins de 10°C)"},{"id":"2","value":"Kitchen chef ZB06B"}]},{"id":336,"id_default_image":"4733","manufacturer_name":"La Maison de la Truffe","price":"44.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Truffe Entière Extra Spécial 1 Truffe"},{"id":"2","value":"Truffe entiére extra spécial 1 truffe"}]},{"id":387,"id_default_image":"1110","manufacturer_name":"Dior ","price":"21000.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"La D de Dior"},{"id":"2","value":"La D de Dior"}]},{"id":389,"id_default_image":"4764","manufacturer_name":"A. Lange & Sohne","price":"20000.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Montre 1815 Or gris"},{"id":"2","value":"1815"}]},{"id":394,"id_default_image":"4797","manufacturer_name":"Oris","price":"1550.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Oris BC4 Retrograde Day"},{"id":"2","value":"Oris BC4 Retrograde Day"}]},{"id":397,"id_default_image":"4864","manufacturer_name":"Tag Heuer","price":"1600.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"FORMULA 1 Calibre S Chronographe"},{"id":"2","value":"FORMULA 1 Calibre S Chronographe"}]},{"id":400,"id_default_image":"4804","manufacturer_name":"Oris","price":"1600.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Oris Divers Small Second, Date"},{"id":"2","value":"Oris Divers Small Second, Date"}]},{"id":401,"id_default_image":"4805","manufacturer_name":"Tag Heuer","price":"1600.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"FORMULA 1 Chronographe"},{"id":"2","value":"FORMULA 1 Chronographe"}]},{"id":406,"id_default_image":"4830","manufacturer_name":"Tag Heuer","price":"2050.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Carrera Calibre 5"},{"id":"2","value":"Carrera Calibre 5"}]},{"id":413,"id_default_image":"4839","manufacturer_name":"Tag Heuer","price":"2100.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Link Chronographe"},{"id":"2","value":"Link Chronographe"}]},{"id":416,"id_default_image":"4842","manufacturer_name":"Longines","price":"2120.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"The Longines Column-Wheel Sports Chronograph"},{"id":"2","value":"The Longines Column-Wheel Sports Chronograph"}]},{"id":417,"id_default_image":"4843","manufacturer_name":"Oris","price":"2130.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Oris 
>   2015-03-23 17:35:15.654 AppTest[5604:70b] str isWilliamsF1 Team Chronograph"},{"id":"2","value":"Oris WilliamsF1 Team Chronograph"}]},{"id":419,"id_default_image":"4815","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"3100.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Arceau"},{"id":"2","value":"Arceau"}]},{"id":430,"id_default_image":"4820","manufacturer_name":"Chaumet","price":"4600.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Dandy Grande Date"},{"id":"2","value":"Dandy Grande Date"}]},{"id":431,"id_default_image":"4819","manufacturer_name":"Jeanrichard","price":"4600.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"1681 Ronde Seconde Centrale"},{"id":"2","value":"1681 round second central"}]},{"id":436,"id_default_image":"4867","manufacturer_name":"Mauboussin","price":"500.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Amour, le Jour se Lève"},{"id":"2","value":"Love, the day to survey"}]},{"id":442,"id_default_image":"1167","manufacturer_name":"Leonor greyl","price":"51.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Masque régénérant à l'huile rare de figue de Barbarie"},{"id":"2","value":"Masque régénérant à l'huile rare de figue de Barbarie"}]},{"id":456,"id_default_image":"4850","manufacturer_name":"Tudor","price":"1580.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Clair de Rose"},{"id":"2","value":"Clair de Rose"}]},{"id":460,"id_default_image":"4853","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"1750.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Heure H Quartz"},{"id":"2","value":"Heure H Quartz"}]},{"id":462,"id_default_image":"1187","manufacturer_name":"Leonor greyl","price":"29.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eclat Naturel"},{"id":"2","value":"Eclat Naturel"}]},{"id":464,"id_default_image":"1188","manufacturer_name":"Leonor greyl","price":"29.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Mousse au Lotus Volumatrice"},{"id":"2","value":"Mousse au Lotus Volumatrice"}]},{"id":466,"id_default_image":"4874","manufacturer_name":"Baume & Mercier","price":"2870.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Linea"},{"id":"2","value":"Linea"}]},{"id":475,"id_default_image":"4876","manufacturer_name":"Dior ","price":"2800.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"La mini D de Dior"},{"id":"2","value":"Mini D de Dior"}]},{"id":476,"id_default_image":"4862","manufacturer_name":"Dior ","price":"2800.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"La Mini D de Dior"},{"id":"2","value":"The Mini D de Dior"}]},{"id":480,"id_default_image":"4878","manufacturer_name":"Raymond Weil","price":"2250.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Noemia"},{"id":"2","value":"Noemia"}]},{"id":484,"id_default_image":"1209","manufacturer_name":"Leonor greyl","price":"22.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème aux Fleurs"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème aux Fleurs"}]},{"id":489,"id_default_image":"1213","manufacturer_name":"Leonor greyl","price":"22.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Laque Souple"},{"id":"2","value":"Flexible Hairspray"}]},{"id":498,"id_default_image":"4887","manufacturer_name":"Chanel","price":"3800.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"J12 Marine Céramique Blanche"},{"id":"2","value":"J12 Marine Céramique Blanche"}]},{"id":504,"id_default_image":"4893","manufacturer_name":"Rado","price":"6240.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"eSenza eSenza Blue Jubilé Cadran Bleu pavé de Saphirs"},{"id":"2","value":"eSenza eSenza Blue Jubilé Cadran Bleu pavé de Saphirs"}]},{"id":518,"id_default_image":"1242","manufacturer_name":"Dior ","price":"321.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Dior Prestige Crème Souveraine"},{"id":"2","value":"Dior Prestige Crème Souveraine"}]},{"id":519,"id_default_image":"1243","manufacturer_name":"Dior ","price":"345.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"L'Or de Vie La Crème"},{"id":"2","value":"L'Or de Vie La Crème"}]},{"id":743,"id_default_image":"1680","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"76.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Génifique Nutrics"},{"id":"2","value":"Génifique Nutrics"}]},{"id":750,"id_default_image":"1687","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"26.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"La Rose Baume Corps"},{"id":"2","value":"La Rose Baume Corps"}]},{"id":784,"id_default_image":"1721","manufacturer_name":"Chanel","price":"366.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Sublimage L'Essence"},{"id":"2","value":"Sublimage L'Essence"}]},{"id":798,"id_default_image":"1737","manufacturer_name":"Guerlain","price":"292.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Orchidée Impériale Crème Cou et Décolleté"},{"id":"2","value":"Orchidée Impériale Crème Cou et Décolleté"}]},{"id":816,"id_default_image":"1753","manufacturer_name":"Guerlain","price":"92.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Super Aqua Sérum"},{"id":"2","value":"Super Aqua Sérum"}]},{"id":822,"id_default_image":"1760","manufacturer_name":"Guerlain","price":"77.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Abeille Royale Huile Visage"},{"id":"2","value":"Abeille Royale Huile Visage"}]},{"id":830,"id_default_image":"1767","manufacturer_name":"Guerlain","price":"108.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Shalimar Extrait de parfum "},{"id":"2","value":"Shalimar Extrait de parfum "}]},{"id":834,"id_default_image":"1771","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"93.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Yvresse Eau de Toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"Yvresse Eau de Toilette"}]},{"id":835,"id_default_image":"1772","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"93.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Nu Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Nu Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":839,"id_default_image":"1776","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"95.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Forever Youth Liberator Fluide FPS 15"},{"id":"2","value":"Forever Youth Liberator Fluide FPS 15"}]},{"id":866,"id_default_image":"1854","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"24.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Rouge Eclat"},{"id":"2","value":"Rouge Eclat"}]},{"id":883,"id_default_image":"1929","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"116.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Supra Sérum Haute Exigence"},{"id":"2","value":"Supra Sérum Haute Exigence"}]},{"id":885,"id_default_image":"1930","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"104.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Multi-Intensive Crème Haute Exigence Soir peaux très sèches"},{"id":"2","value":"Multi-Intensive Crème Haute Exigence Soir peaux très sèches"}]},{"id":887,"id_default_image":"1936","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"104.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Multi-Intensive Crème Haute Exigence Soir"},{"id":"2","value":"Multi-Intensive Crème Haute Exigence Soir"}]},{"id":895,"id_default_image":"1969","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"97.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Capital Lumière Nuit Peaux Sèches"},{"id":"2","value":"Capital Lumière Nuit Peaux Sèches"}]},{"id":896,"id_default_image":"1970","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"97.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Capital Lumière Nuit Soin anti-âge revitalisant"},{"id":"2","value":"Capital Lumière Nuit Soin anti-âge revitalisant"}]},{"id":898,"id_default_image":"1981","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"92.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Capital Lumière Jour Peaux Sèches"},{"id":"2","value":"Capital Lumière Jour Peaux Sèches"}]},{"id":900,"id_default_image":"1987","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"92.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Capital Lumière Jour SPF15 Soin anti-âge unifiant"},{"id":"2","value":"Capital Lumière Jour SPF15 Soin anti-âge unifiant"}]},{"id":911,"id_default_image":"2047","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"54.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Sérum Corps Peau Neuve"},{"id":"2","value":"Sérum Corps Peau Neuve"}]},{"id":913,"id_default_image":"2053","manufacturer_name":"Clarins","price":"52.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Masvelt Crème Anti-Rondeurs Rebelles"},{"id":"2","value":"Masvelt Crème Anti-Rondeurs Rebelles"}]},{"id":961,"id_default_image":"2208","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"30.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Beurre de Sel Exfoliant"},{"id":"2","value":"Butter scrub salt"}]},{"id":963,"id_default_image":"4966","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"1235.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Bracelet Charms balle or"},{"id":"2","value":"Bracelet Charms ball gold"}]},{"id":973,"id_default_image":"4975","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"2260.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Bague Puzzle Toi & Moi"},{"id":"2","value":"Ring Puzzle Toi & Moi"}]},{"id":989,"id_default_image":"2255","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"37.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Hydratant Essentiel de Jour Peaux normales à sèches"},{"id":"2","value":"Most of day normal to dry skin moisturizer"}]},{"id":1003,"id_default_image":"2288","manufacturer_name":"ALEXANDER WANG","price":"755.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Veste sans manches en crêpe à effet tablier dans le dos "},{"id":"2","value":"Jacket sleeveless crepe effect deck in the back"}]},{"id":1127,"id_default_image":"3081","manufacturer_name":"Beats by Dre","price":"399.950000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Beatbox portable"},{"id":"2","value":"Beatbox portable"}]},{"id":1129,"id_default_image":"3096","manufacturer_name":"Beats by Dre","price":"399.950000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Beatbox portable"},{"id":"2","value":"Beatbox portable"}]},{"id":1186,"id_default_image":"3269","manufacturer_name":"Carita","price":"52.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème-en-lait demaquillante jeunesse"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème-en-lait demaquillante jeunesse"}]},{"id":1191,"id_default_image":"3275","manufacturer_name":"Carita","price":"65.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Ideal Hydratation Sérum Des Lagons"},{"id":"2","value":"Ideal Hydratation Sérum Des Lagons"}]},{"id":1198,"id_default_image":"3282","manufacturer_name":"Carita","price":"36.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Lotion Nacrée"},{"id":"2","value":"Lotion Nacrée"}]},{"id":1202,"id_default_image":"3286","manufacturer_name":"Carita","price":"36.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau des Lagons"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau des Lagons"}]},{"id":1233,"id_default_image":"3327","manufacturer_name":"Caron","price":"220.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Parfum \"N'aimez que moi\" "},{"id":"2","value":"Parfum \"N'aimez que moi\" "}]},{"id":1235,"id_default_image":"3330","manufacturer_name":"Caron","price":"220.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Parfum \"Délire de roses\" "},{"id":"2","value":"Parfum \"Délire de roses\" "}]},{"id":1236,"id_default_image":"16704","manufacturer_name":"Caron","price":"52.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Poudre libre rose "},{"id":"2","value":"Poudre libre rose "}]},{"id":1326,"id_default_image":"3604","manufacturer_name":"Bernardaud","price":"281.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Coffret théière or + boite de thé"},{"id":"2","value":"Coffret théière or + boite de thé"}]},{"id":1327,"id_default_image":"3605","manufacturer_name":"Bernardaud","price":"281.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Coffret théière platine + boite de thé"},{"id":"2","value":"Teapot box Platinum + box tea"}]},{"id":1328,"id_default_image":"3607","manufacturer_name":"Bernardaud","price":"243.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Coffret 1 théière + 1 boite de thé"},{"id":"2","value":"Box 1 teapot + 1 box of tea"}]},{"id":1329,"id_default_image":"3608","manufacturer_name":"Bernardaud","price":"232.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Théière or"},{"id":"2","value":"Teapot gold"}]},{"id":1330,"id_default_image":"3609","manufacturer_name":"Bernardaud","price":"232.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Théière platine"},{"id":"2","value":"Platinum teapot"}]},{"id":1331,"id_default_image":"3610","manufacturer_name":"Bernardaud","price":"199.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Théière verte"},{"id":"2","value":"Green teapot"}]},{"id":1556,"id_default_image":"4400","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"121.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Cologne Absolue Ambre Nue Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Cologne Absolue Ambre Nue Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1557,"id_default_image":"4401","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"100.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Cologne Absolue Vétiver Fatal Eau de Cologne"},{"id":"2","value":"Cologne Absolue Vétiver Fatal Eau de Cologne"}]},{"id":1558,"id_default_image":"4402","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"110.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Cologne Absolue Vanille Insensée Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Cologne Absolue Vanille Insensée Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1560,"id_default_image":"4404","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"121.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Cologne Absolue Rose Anonyme Eau de Cologne"},{"id":"2","value":"Cologne Absolue Rose Anonyme Eau de Cologne"}]},{"id":1561,"id_default_image":"4405","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"99.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Grand Néroli Cologne Absolue Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Grand Néroli Cologne Absolue Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1562,"id_default_image":"4406","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"110.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Trèfle Pur Cologne Absolue Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Trèfle Pur Cologne Absolue Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1563,"id_default_image":"4407","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"165.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Ecrin Absolu Gold Leather Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Ecrin Absolu Gold Leather Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1564,"id_default_image":"4408","manufacturer_name":"Atelier Cologne","price":"149.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Cologne Absolue Silver Iris Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Cologne Absolue Silver Iris Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1566,"id_default_image":"4410","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"48.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Tourmaline Charged Crème Hydratante"},{"id":"2","value":"Tourmaline Charged hydrating cream"}]},{"id":1575,"id_default_image":"4419","manufacturer_name":"Carolina Herrera","price":"66.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"212 VIP Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"212 VIP Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1587,"id_default_image":"4431","manufacturer_name":"Chanel","price":"110.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Le Lift Crème - 50g"},{"id":"2","value":"Le Lift Crème"}]},{"id":1595,"id_default_image":"4439","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"34.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème Lavante au Citron"},{"id":"2","value":"Cleansing with lemon cream"}]},{"id":1600,"id_default_image":"4445","manufacturer_name":"Clinique","price":"55.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Superdefense SPF20 Hydratant Défense Quotidienne"},{"id":"2","value":"Superdefense SPF20 Hydratant Défense Quotidienne"}]},{"id":1613,"id_default_image":"4463","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"53.300000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Coffret eau de parfum Parisienne"},{"id":"2","value":"Coffret eau de parfum Parisienne"}]},{"id":1620,"id_default_image":"4474","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"85.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de parfum Cinéma"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de perfume theater"}]},{"id":1627,"id_default_image":"4481","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"59.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème forever light creator"},{"id":"2","value":"Cream forever light creator"}]},{"id":1631,"id_default_image":"4484","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"87.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Sérum forever youth liberator"},{"id":"2","value":"Serum forever youth liberator"}]},{"id":1633,"id_default_image":"4486","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"95.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Fluide FPS 15"},{"id":"2","value":"Fluide FPS 15"}]},{"id":1641,"id_default_image":"4494","manufacturer_name":"Saint Laurent","price":"72.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème riche pour le corps"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème riche pour le corp"}]},{"id":1647,"id_default_image":"4500","manufacturer_name":"Viktor & Rolf","price":"145.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Flowerbomb eau de toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"Flowerbomb eau de toilette"}]},{"id":1653,"id_default_image":"4506","manufacturer_name":"Dior ","price":"79.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Capture Totale One Essential Régénérateur cel
>   2015-03-23 17:35:15.661 AppTest[5604:70b] str islulaire intense"},{"id":"2","value":"Capture total One Essential cellular regenerator intense"}]},{"id":1657,"id_default_image":"4510","manufacturer_name":"Van Cleef & Arpels","price":"76.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de parfum Féerie"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de parfum Féerie"}]},{"id":1660,"id_default_image":"4513","manufacturer_name":"Van Cleef & Arpels","price":"73.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de toilette Gem"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de toilette Gem"}]},{"id":1666,"id_default_image":"4519","manufacturer_name":"Dolce & Gabbana","price":"61.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"The One Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"The One Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1668,"id_default_image":"4521","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"86.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de parfum Habanita"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de perfume Habanita"}]},{"id":1669,"id_default_image":"4522","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"55.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Xtend Your Youth Crème hydratante - 50g"},{"id":"2","value":"Xtend Your Youth cream moisturizing, smoothing and antioxidant"}]},{"id":1675,"id_default_image":"4527","manufacturer_name":false,"price":"65.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème ultra-hydratante - 50g"},{"id":"2","value":"Lineless ® Infinite Moisture ® combination cream"}]},{"id":1691,"id_default_image":"17108","manufacturer_name":"Lanvin","price":"99.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de parfum Arpège"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de parfum Arpège"}]},{"id":1698,"id_default_image":"4551","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"86.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de parfum Hypnôse"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de parfum Hypnôse"}]},{"id":1705,"id_default_image":"4558","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"73.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de parfum Miracle so magic"},{"id":"2","value":"Eau de parfum Miracle so magic"}]},{"id":1707,"id_default_image":"4560","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"83.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Coffret de prestige eau de parfum hypnôse"},{"id":"2","value":"Coffret de prestige eau de parfum hypnôse"}]},{"id":1709,"id_default_image":"4562","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"106.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Visionnaire LR 2412 4 %"},{"id":"2","value":"Visionnaire LR 2412 4 %"}]},{"id":1710,"id_default_image":"4563","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"56.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème de jour Hydra zen (Peaux normales à mixtes)"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème de jour Hydra zen"}]},{"id":1711,"id_default_image":"4564","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"105.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Advanced génifique"},{"id":"2","value":"Advanced génifique"}]},{"id":1712,"id_default_image":"4565","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"76.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Génifique crème"},{"id":"2","value":"Génifique crème"}]},{"id":1714,"id_default_image":"4567","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"62.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème de nuit Hydrazen"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème de nuit Hydrazen"}]},{"id":1718,"id_default_image":"4571","manufacturer_name":"Lancôme","price":"106.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Rénergie multi-lift reviva plasma"},{"id":"2","value":"Rénergie multi-lift reviva plasma"}]},{"id":1729,"id_default_image":"4582","manufacturer_name":"Elie Saab","price":"50.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"ELIE SAAB Le Parfum Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"ELIE SAAB Le Parfum Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1731,"id_default_image":"4584","manufacturer_name":"Estée Lauder","price":"50.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Modern Muse Eau de parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Modern Muse Eau de perfume"}]},{"id":1734,"id_default_image":"4590","manufacturer_name":"Akris","price":"2370.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Veste imprimée"},{"id":"2","value":"Printed jacket"}]},{"id":1738,"id_default_image":"4599","manufacturer_name":"Akris","price":"960.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Tunique imprimée en coton"},{"id":"2","value":"Printed cotton tunic"}]},{"id":1762,"id_default_image":"4646","manufacturer_name":"Givenchy","price":"58.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Play For Her Eau de Toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"Play For Her Eau de Toilette"}]},{"id":1772,"id_default_image":"4656","manufacturer_name":"Guerlain","price":"55.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Shalimar Eau de Parfum\t"},{"id":"2","value":"Shalimar Eau de Parfum\t"}]},{"id":1787,"id_default_image":"4670","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"60.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Jour d'Hermès Absolu Eau de Parfum\t "},{"id":"2","value":"Jour d'Hermès Absolu Eau de Parfum\t "}]},{"id":1788,"id_default_image":"4671","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"87.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Terre d'Hermès Eau Très Fraîche Eau de Toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"Terre d'Hermès Eau Très Fraîche Eau de Toilette"}]},{"id":1789,"id_default_image":"4672","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"72.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Voyage d'Hermès Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Voyage d'Hermès Parfum"}]},{"id":1790,"id_default_image":"4673","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"85.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau de Mandarine Ambrée Eau de Cologne"},{"id":"2","value":"Water of Mandarine amber Eau de Cologne"}]},{"id":1791,"id_default_image":"4675","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"61.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Terre d'Hermès Eau de Toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"Terre d'Hermès Eau de Toilette"}]},{"id":1792,"id_default_image":"4676","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"78.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau des Merveilles Eau de Toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"The wonders Eau de Toilette water"}]},{"id":1793,"id_default_image":"4677","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"65.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Un Jardin sur le Nil Eau de Toilette"},{"id":"2","value":"A garden on the Nile Eau de Toilette"}]},{"id":1794,"id_default_image":"4678","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"50.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Eau d'Orange Verte Eau de Cologne"},{"id":"2","value":"Orange green water of Cologne"}]},{"id":1795,"id_default_image":"4679","manufacturer_name":"Hermès","price":"89.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Calèche Soie de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Caleche perfume silk"}]},{"id":1799,"id_default_image":"4684","manufacturer_name":"Jimmy Choo","price":"64.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Flash Coffret Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Flash box Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1801,"id_default_image":"4686","manufacturer_name":"Jimmy Choo","price":"64.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Jimmy Choo Flash Coffret Eau de Parfum"},{"id":"2","value":"Jimmy Choo Flash box Eau de Parfum"}]},{"id":1806,"id_default_image":"4691","manufacturer_name":"La Prairie","price":"271.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Ice crystal Huile Sèche Cellulaire Suisse"},{"id":"2","value":"Ice crystal Huile Sèche Cellulaire Suisse"}]},{"id":1808,"id_default_image":"4693","manufacturer_name":"La Prairie","price":"369.900000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème Caviar Luxe Visage"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème Caviar Luxe Visage"}]},{"id":1815,"id_default_image":"4700","manufacturer_name":"La Prairie","price":"183.500000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Crème de Jour Anti-Age SPF 30"},{"id":"2","value":"Crème de Jour Anti-Age SPF 30"}]},{"id":1856,"id_default_image":"4931","manufacturer_name":"Christofle","price":"250.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Sel et poivre"},{"id":"2","value":"Sel et poivre"}]},{"id":1903,"id_default_image":"5079","manufacturer_name":"Ermenegildo Zegna","price":"150.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Echarpe drapeau"},{"id":"2","value":"Flag scarf"}]},{"id":1904,"id_default_image":"5078","manufacturer_name":"Ermenegildo Zegna","price":"255.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Echarpe jacquard à chevre"},{"id":"2","value":"Scarf pattern to goat"}]},{"id":2049,"id_default_image":"5440","manufacturer_name":"Qlocktwo","price":"449.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Qlocktwo touch "},{"id":"2","value":"Qlocktwo touch "}]},{"id":2050,"id_default_image":"5445","manufacturer_name":"Qlocktwo","price":"449.000000","name":[{"id":"1","value":"Qlocktwo touch "},{"id":"2","value":"Qlocktwo touch "}]},

Comment: You see that `error` parameter that you set to `nil`?  You shouldn't have done that.

Comment: Yes, that is mostly likely that is the answer.

Comment: Would be nice to see the JSON you received as a string.

Comment: See edited question please, well the json string is too long so I couldn't make all the json result in the body of the question

Comment: Your data seems to be a `NSDictionary` at top level (with a key "products", maybe others but it's hard to read with this indentation/format). Check if your JSON is valid (there are online tools for that), and use the `NSError` parameter and check it.

Comment: Your JSON is an actual Dictionary. You should create a pointer object to an NSDictionary as someone pointed out below. I don't see any reason for you to take the whole dictionary and transform it into a String. You should work with the dictionary as it is.

Comment: I did Like this `NSDictionary* magazineJsonArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];`and I tried to use this dictionary but it returns null value, I used nsstring just to show it in log and to be sure that may returned value is not null

Comment: I don't know if it can return null value because it is too long, any suggestions please ?

Comment: If the JSON data is too long (like tens of megabytes) it might crash your phone, or it might take long to load, but that size will not make it return nil. I've used JSON data that was so long you couldn't open it in TextEdit, and NSJSONSerializer has no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data all looks reasonable, at least the start of it.

First step is to check the NSError that you should have received, where you passed nil as the error parameter. That will tell you what's wrong.

Sometimes servers send JSON with data that doesn't belong there. For example, extra zero bytes at the beginning or end or a byte order marker in the middle of your text. If that is the case, you need to examine your data carefully. Check if the NSData contains any zero bytes, for example.

Comment: this is the error : Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unterminated string around character 3366.) UserInfo=0x7bf98910 {NSDebugDescription=Unterminated string around character 3366.

how can I fix it ?

Comment: And here second error : Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7a687a30 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: I did `[mutableData appendData:data];` and the problem was solved. Thank you, your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialize the `magazineJsonArray` object?

```
NSDictionary* magazineJsonArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

I strongly recommended to visit the following article.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html

Here is an example:
[Parsing a JSON array with dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802750/parsing-a-json-array-with-dictionaries)

Comment: I know this article, I want to know why my code is returning null value from non null data

Comment: Have you initialize the magazineJsonArray object? NSDictionary* magazineJsonArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

Comment: yes I did but it doesn't work, I can see data is not null in the log, and when I converted data to nsstring, and I did nslog, the string was shown in the log divided into 3 parts, can it be caused because the data is long ? because I tried with other url and it works fine

Comment: Correct answer! It seems that the OP doesn't know how to work with Dictionaries. The JSON object retrieved is an actual Dictionary so use it accordingly.

Comment: In my code I did : `NSDictionary* magazineJsonArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];`but it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Your object is a `Dictionary` so you should create an `NSDictionary` object for it and handle the data accordingly.

In the future, if you don't know the type of data you're receiving you could type-check the data like this:

```
+ (id)deserializeJSONfromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *jsonData = [self downloadDataFromURL:url];

    id jsonObject;

    if (jsonData) {
        jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                        options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                          error:&error];
        if (jsonObject && !error) {
            NSLog(@"Success!");
        }
        else if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed! Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

+ (BOOL)isJSONFromURL:(NSString *)urlAsString typeOfClass:(Class)classType {

    id classObject =[classType new];

    NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

    id jsonObject = [self deserializeJSONfromURL:dataURL];

    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[classType class]]) {
        NSLog(@"The JSON data is %@ class compliant.", [classType description]);
        return YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"The JSON data is not %@ class compliant.", [classType description]);
    classObject = nil;
    jsonObject = nil;

    return NO;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
if ([MyDeserializerClass isJSONFromURL:@"anURL" typeOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
      //is an NSDictionary compliant. Do something with it.
}
```

For a fast check you could try an NSLog statement like this:

```
NSLog(@"Type of JSON data %@", [[jsonObject class] description]);
```