# How to Parse JSON Response and utilize it in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am developing an iOS app. I am getting JSON response, how do I Parse it? It is comprising of two different buttons data. How do I count it and show on buttons details?

JSON Response:

```
{
 0 =     {
        date = "0000-00-00";
        "is_active" = 1;
        project = "New project";
        "project_desc" = "New project";
        "project_id" = 3;
        time = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 6;
    };
    1 =     {
        date = "2017-01-04";
        "is_active" = 1;
        project = "New Project 2";
        "project_desc" = "New Project 2";
        "project_id" = 4;
        time = "06:29:54";
        "user_id" = 6;
    };
    status = 1;
}
```

Parsing Code:

```
- (void)serverDidReceiveResponse:(NSDictionary *)response{
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    for (NSDictionary *projectValue in response) {
       _projectName = [projectValue valueForKey:@"time"];
        _active = [projectValue valueForKey:@"is_active"];
    }
```

Comment: _projectName = [[projectValue valueForKey:@"time"]objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: [<NSTaggedPointerString 0xa000000000000301> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key time. This error will display To doing this type

Comment: Nsarray *jsonreponse = _response; now you have to manage all with jsonreponse you did not need forloop and all . and ya tell what kind of data type of these two  _projectName and _active ?

Comment: This type also show nil value

Comment: Try searching for pre-existing answers before asking a new one. This has been [asked plenty of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+ios+objective+c+parse)

Comment: get the each values for the key from the dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a JSON array with dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802750/parsing-a-json-array-with-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(NSDictionary*projectvalue in response) 
{
    for(NSDictionary *projectvalue1 in projectvalue) 
    {
        _projectName = [projectValue1 valueForKey:@"time"]; _active = [projectValue1 valueForKey:@"is_active"]; 
    } 
}
```